# If condition is not checked multiple times inside a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to find the number of times a number is shifted from its original sequence. I swap the number in ascending order and I count the number of swaps; if the count is >3 I break from the loop.

But so far when I check the numbers the first iteration only the if condition executes and after that it doesn't check for the condition. I am trying to understand why the if condition isn't executing.

```
 def minimumBribes(q):
       x=q.copy()
       lis=[]
       i=0
       j=0
       count=0
       flag=0
       while i< len(q):
           k=j+1
           a=q[j]
           b=q[k]
           print(a,b)
           if a>b:
             print(a>b)
             x.pop(x.index(a))
             x.insert(x.index(b),a)

             print(x)
             flag+=1
             if flag>3:
                print('Too chaotic')
                break
             else:
                j+=1
           i+=1
       print(count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = int(input())

    for t_itr in range(t):
        n = int(input())

        q = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

        minimumBribes(q)
```

Comment: i apologise if my code isnt indented im new to stack overflow still trying to figure out how it works

Comment: this is a hackerrank problem iirc:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem  - did you consult hackerranks Tips/Hint pages correlating with the problem you try to solve?

Comment: Can you indent your code? It's impossible to understand what's inside the if.

Comment: dome i have edited it

Answer (score 0):

I walked through your code with a debugger and the if-Statement is never entered if the first item in your list is greater than the second.

Say your list looks like this:

```
q = [1, 2, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6, 0, 10]
```

Then the first iteration of the while loop would look like that:

```
k = j + 1 # k = 1
a = q[j] # a = 1
b = q[k] # b = 2
print(a, b) # 1, 2
if a > b: # false
    ...
```

Since your j is only increased inside the if-Statement, the values for a and b never change. 
Also: I could not figure out why you need the variables t, n and lis. Are they used in another part of your code? If so, please remove them from your question, since they are confusing.

Also another hint for writing a question: while your code is executable on its own (a big plus), the input was not obvious to me initially. Providing a concrete input (in your case the list q) helps a lot in identifying the problem.

Hope I was of help.